# Problem with yarn dependency using the rhino R package

Tags: r, node.js, shiny, sass, yarnpkg

I am trying the new R package [rhino](https://appsilon.github.io/rhino/index.html) from the Appsilon team to build shiny apps.

Running on a Windows10 laptop I installed the dependencies node.js and yarn as described in this [tutorial](https://appsilon.github.io/rhino/articles/tutorial/create-your-first-rhino-app.html#dependencies).

Here is the output of `rhino::diagnostics()` :

```
Windows 10 x64 build 19042
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
rhino: 1.0.0
node: v16.15.0
yarn: 1.22.15
```

Running `rhino::build_sass()` gives me this error:

```
yarn run v1.22.15
$ sass --no-source-map --style=compressed root/app/styles/main.scss:root/app/static/css/app.min.css
Error reading root\app\styles\main.scss: no such file or directory.
error Command failed with exit code 66.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error:
! System command 'yarn' exited with status 66.
i If you can't use Node.js and yarn, try using sass: 'r' configuration.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I am puzzled by the paths in the call to "sass" that start with "root/app". My app is located in my home directory:
"C:/Users/XXX/Documents/workspace/rhino_dummy"

Is it possible that these paths are wrong in the call?

---

Luckily, the suggested alternative with the deprecated `libsass` interpreter works for the sass example in the tutorial. It would be nice to have node.js with sass working on Windows10 for future more complex apps.

---

### Edit 1, after Kat's comment

Thanks Kat for the quick feedback. I added `sass` via `yarn add sass` and tried again same error:

```
> rhino::build_sass()
yarn run v1.22.15
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
$ sass --no-source-map --style=compressed root/app/styles/main.scss:root/app/static/css/app.min.css
Error reading root\app\styles\main.scss: no such file or directory.
error Command failed with exit code 66.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error:
! System command 'yarn' exited with status 66.
i If you can't use Node.js and yarn, try using sass: 'r' configuration.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The warning is coming from the `pckage.json` file that was created by calling `yarn` inside my R project folder. It has only minimal content:

```
# package.json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.51.0"
  }
}
```

Out of curiosity, I tried to compile the javascript example, also failed with very similar error regarding folder paths:

```
> rhino::build_js()
yarn run v1.22.15
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
$ webpack
assets by status 0 bytes [cached] 1 asset

ERROR in main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\js\index.js' in 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node'
resolve 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\js\index.js' in 'C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node'
  using description file: C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\package.json (relative path: .)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration using description file: C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\package.json (relative path: ./root/app/js/index.js)
      no extension
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\js\index.js doesn't exist
      .js
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\js\index.js.js doesn't exist
      .json
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\js\index.js.json doesn't exist
      .wasm
        Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\js\index.js.wasm doesn't exist
      as directory
        C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\js\index.js doesn't exist

webpack 5.69.0 compiled with 1 error in 162 ms
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error in `system_yarn()`:
! System command 'yarn' exited with status 1.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Comment: It looks like they are both deprecated, so you may not be losing all that much with `libsass`. However, you could try adding [the Sass package with `Yarn` directly](https://yarnpkg.com/package/sass). I don't know if it will work with Rhino, but it's worth a try. It doesn't look like that's part of those instructions, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Node.js functions to work on Windows 10, you'll need to enable [Developer Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#active-developer-mode) on your system as mentioned in our [How-to: Use Rhino on Windows](https://appsilon.github.io/rhino/articles/how-to/use-rhino-on-windows.html) article. This is necessary for symbolic links to work on Windows (and the `.rhino/node/root` file is a symbolic link to the root of the project).

After you do that, delete the `.rhino/node` directory from your project, or run `rhino:::add_node(clean = TRUE)` in the root of your project.

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround

This answer is only a workaround, if you cannot enable developer mode on windows (see Kamil Zyla's post for more information).

It looks like the folder name "root" in the error messages is a broken variable.

The folder `...\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root` does not exist, but the substructures do exit:

- `app\styles\main.scss`
- `app\js\index.js`
- `...\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node`

**Fix step1**

- I tried my luck and created the folder "root": `C:\Users\XXX\Documents\workspace\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root`
- copied `rhino_dummy\app\styles\main.scss` to `rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\styles\main.scss`
- copied `rhino_dummy\app\js\index.js` to `rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\js\index.js`
- running `rhino::build_sass()` and `rhino::build_js()` now worked!

`rhino::build_sass()`

```
yarn run v1.22.15
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
$ sass --no-source-map --style=compressed root/app/styles/main.scss:root/app/static/css/app.min.css
Done in 0.45s.
```

`rhino::build_js()`

```
yarn run v1.22.15
warning ..\..\package.json: No license field
$ webpack
asset app.min.js 470 bytes [compared for emit] [minimized] (name: main)
runtime modules 670 bytes 3 modules
./root/app/js/index.js 113 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.69.0 compiled successfully in 846 ms
Done in 2.58s.
```

**Fix step2**

- copy results back to "static" folder, where they are expected by shiny/rhino
- copy `rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\static\css\app.min.css` to `rhino_dummy\app\static\css\app.min.css`
- copy `\rhino_dummy\.rhino\node\root\app\static\js\app.min.js` to `\rhino_dummy\app\static\js\app.min.js`
- launch the app via `shiny::shinyAppDir(".")`
- click the button from the tutorial ;-)

---

### Edit1

Checking the github repo of rhino

SASS

- definition of [build_sass()](https://github.com/Appsilon/rhino/blob/95b7260060ce069b8dfdb09c15047dc54ad27b06/R/tools.R#L205)
  calling `yarn("build-sass")`
- definition of [build-sass](https://github.com/Appsilon/rhino/blob/7a2635077c48c73528bb2c7193f1eb5d6c2aed26/inst/templates/node/package.json#L5)
  showing hard-coded `root/app/styles/main.scss`

JS

- definition of [build_js()](https://github.com/Appsilon/rhino/blob/95b7260060ce069b8dfdb09c15047dc54ad27b06/R/tools.R#L140)
  calling `yarn("build-js")`
- definition of ["webpack" build-js](https://github.com/Appsilon/rhino/blob/7a2635077c48c73528bb2c7193f1eb5d6c2aed26/inst/templates/node/webpack.config.babel.js) also showing hard-coded "root" in file paths

Comment: I opened an issue at the rhino github page: https://github.com/Appsilon/rhino/issues/276